# Magento2: How to set VAT rates in store

Tags: magento2

I did not define any rates in the store before adding products. I have entered all prices in the store gross (with VAT).

1) Now I have set tax rates:
[image]

Now magento has added 23% to all prices products in the store. 
But I do not want to add an additional 23%.

I want it to display only the tax price on the amount I already have in the store - without adding additional amounts.

anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Stores > Configuration > Sales > Tax

**change this section.**

```
Catalog Prices ->> Including Tax
```

**read below**

> This sets whether catalog prices entered from Magento Admin include
>   tax.